# how to implement build in adobe pdf reader in android app

Tags: java, android

I am doing an assignment to open pdf in an android app but the device has not install any pdf viewer.

How can I easily to create a build in pdf viewer in my app??

I have no ideas...

Thanks

Comment: I am too looking for the same.. Any updates on this?

Comment: Find some source form stackoverflow, but it is using another app to open pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Is the PDF file local to the device or on a remote server?  If it is remote then you could use the [google viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer) to render the PDF for display in a `WebView` or the android web browser.